# read a file into a buffer, but program crashes at fread after calling fseek

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault, fread, fseek

I want to read a file into a buffer. I get segmentation fault at `fread()`. Looks like `ftell()` gives correct size back. But then things go wrong. Will `fseek()` modify `f`? Why `fread()` does not work?

```
int pk_load_file( const char *filename )
{
    FILE *f;
    int size;
    unsigned char *buf;

    if( ( f = fopen( filename, "rb" ) ) == NULL )
        return -1;

    fseek( f, 0, SEEK_END );

    if( ( size = ftell( f ) ) == -1 )
    {
        fclose( f );
        return -2;
    }

    fseek( f, 0, SEEK_SET );

    if( fread( buf, 1, size, f ) != size )
    {
        fclose( f );
        return -3;
    }

    fclose( f );

    return( 0 );
 }
```

Comment: Do not use `fseek()/ftell()` to compute the size of a file, especially in binary mode.  Per the C Standard (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf): "A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls with a whence value of SEEK_END".  Also see:  https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is

```
if( fread( buf, 1, size, f ) != size )
```

in above case, you're using `buf` uninitialized. You need to allocate memory to `buf` before using it.

Being uninitialized, `buf` can point to any memory location, which is not accessible by the process. So, trying to access the memory pointed by `buf` invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Segmentation fault is one of the side effects.

Solution: You may allocate memory to `buf` using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family.

Comment: @rakeb.void Why? `fseek( f, 0, SEEK_SET );` what it's suppossed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Correct code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int pk_load_file( const char *filename ) {
    FILE *f;
    int size;
    unsigned char *buf;

    if ((f = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);

    if ((size = ftell(f)) == -1) {
        fclose(f);
        return -2;
    }

    buf = malloc(size); // here is the magic. you need to allocate "size" bytes

    if (buf == NULL) {
        fclose(f);
        return -3;
    }

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if (fread(buf, 1, size, f) != size) {
        fclose(f);
        return -4;
    }

    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fread reads data 'as is', does not add anything. Edit your original code and show how you try to free buf.

Answer (score 0):

```
 unsigned char *buf;
```

As above answer described it gives undefined behaviour so either use dynamic allocation or declare it as an array ,

```
 #define  MAX_LENGTH 1024
 unsigned char buf[MAX_LENGTH];
```

And the pass it to `fread()` .

Comment: You should check if size is above max length, and handle the case correctly.

Comment: @Leandros  Yes ,that condition should be checked .